# Map on Android flickers after implementing dialog for datepicker

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I was successfully able to implement map in fragment tab over android without any flicker , suddenly after implementing click handlers for action bar which initiates dialog fragment for datepicker , my map flickers and sometimes overlaps with action bar . What might be the possible cos of error ?

[image]

As you can see above , map is overlapping date picker dialog after flicker , and after I touch datepicker dialog , map goes in background. Similar problem happens with action bar , i.e upon flicker action bar becomes transparent and map is visible and sometimes it runs fine

ps: I am implementing GoogleMapV2

What can be the possible cause for such flicker and overlapping issues? Thanks in advance , any hint is also appreciated .